# Error Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, json, loops

First post here so apologies in advance if this is an incorrect format. I am working with the Instagram API to pull images. The Instagram API only returns 1 page of images at a time, but offers pagination and next_url to grab the next page of images. When I use the function fetchInstagramAPI below, to grab only the first page, the php code works fine.

When I attempt to use the loopPages function together with the fetchInstagramAPI function, to try and grab all pages at once, I receive the error "Using $this when not in object context". Any idea? Thank you for the help in advance.

Function fetchInstagramAPI gets our data

```
<?php
  function fetchInstagramAPI($url){
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
         $contents = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch); 
         return json_decode($contents);
    }
```

Function loopPages uses pagination and next_url to grab all pages of images

```
  function loopPages($url){

    $gotAllResults = false;
    $results = array();

    while(!$gotAllResults) {
    $result = $this->fetchInstagramAPI($url);
    $results[] = $result;

    if (!property_exists($result->pagination, 'next_url')) {
        $gotAllResults = true;
    } else {
        $url = $result->pagination->next_url;
    }
}

return $results;

}
```

This pulls, parses, then displays the images in a browser

```
  $all_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?client_id={$clientid}';
  $media = loopPages($all_url);

  foreach ($media->data as $post): ?>
    <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail, low_resoulution, standard_resolution) -->
    <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: You should read about classes and objects in PHP. This error is cause because you are trying to call a function which I am presuming has been grafted out of a class. You may be able to get this to work by changing: $this->fetchInstagramAPI($url) TO fetchInstagramAPI($url)

Comment: Thank you, I will look into classes and objects. If I take out $this-> then I am shown " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in line "foreach ($media->data as $post): ?>". Any idea? I am new to PHP but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP and many object oriented languages `$this` is a reference to the current object (or the calling object). Because your code don't seem to be in any class `$this` doesn't exists. Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) link for PHP classes and objects.

Since you have just defined your functions in the file you can try calling the function with `$result = fetchInstagramAPI($url);` (without `$this`).

**edit**:

For foreach check if `$media->data` is in fact an array and try another syntax which i think is easier to read.

**edit2**:

Since you now know how your `$media` looks like you can wrap around another foreach loop that will iterate through the pages:

```
foreach ($media as $page){
  foreach ($page->data as $post) {
    echo '<!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail, low_resoulution, standard_resolution) -->';
    echo '<a class="group" rel="group1" href="' . $post->images->standard_resolution->url . '"><img src="' . $post->images->thumbnail->url . '"></a>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. If I take out $this, to then have "$result = fetchInstagramAPI($url);" I am given the error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in line "foreach ($media->data as $post): ?>". Any idea? Thank you very much for the help, I am new to PHP

Comment: make sure you are including the file that has the function fetchInstagramAPI defined.

Comment: @JustinE I am. All the code above is in the same php file. I took out $this and now see Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error.

Comment: Check to make sure your json_decode is not returning false...so do this: `if($ret = json_decode($contents)){ return $ret; }` Foreach can only iterate over an array, not a Boolean or string value.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can do `var_dump($media->data)` and see what kind of object is it and its structure.

Comment: Thank you @pajaja. It now works if I have "foreach ($media[0]->data as $post)". media[0] pulls the first page, media[1] pulls the second page, and so on. Any way for this to just pull all the pages automatically?

Comment: You can add another loop that will iterate trough the first level of the array. I edited my answer